# android sdk start activity from preference.xml

Tags: android, xml, sdk, preferenceactivity, start-activity

I'm using an account-authenticator with an accountPreferences reference to a prefs.xml. How can I attach a PreferenceActivity to this prefs.xml file? My file is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<SwitchPreference
    android:key="@string/key"
    android:summary="@string/summary" />

    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="app_package"
        android:targetClass="app_package.MyPrefsActivity" />
</PreferenceScreen>

with its definition in manifest:

<activity android:name=".MyPrefsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

at the moment my prefs screen is launched, but without acitivity attached to it. Also, how can I get and set prefs value of the switch?